# sed replace with special characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm having some problems with sed where I need the replacement has a special regex character in it.

I've seen answers on stackoverflow, but none seem to work for my problem.

I'm trying to replace the date in a variable as follows:

```
date=$(date "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
echo "DATE" | sed -e "s/\bDATE/${date}/g;"
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: You need to escape the `/` in the `date` output or use a different delimiter in `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply change the delimiter, it suffices to make your expression work.

```
date=$(date "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
echo "DATE" | sed -e "s|\bDATE|${date}|g"
```